# .Net Core error System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type is already being tracked

Tags: c#, .net

i´m developing a web api with angular and .Net Core.
I'm really new in .Net, but when i try to update a process at this endpoint, i get this error:
"An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'EtapaEmpleado' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'IdEtapa', 'IdEmpleado'} is already being tracked".

This is my code:

```
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutEtapa([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] EditEtapaDto editEtapaDto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != editEtapaDto.IdEtapa)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            
            var preEtapa = _mapper.Map<Etapa>(editEtapaDto);
            //Prueba
            foreach(var a in preEtapa.EtapaEmpleado)
            {
                var preEtapaEmpleado=_mapper.Map<EtapaEmpleado>(a);
                if(_context.EtapaEmpleado.Where(z=>z.IdEmpleado==preEtapaEmpleado.IdEmpleado).Count()>0 && _context.EtapaEmpleado.Where(x=>x.IdEtapa==preEtapaEmpleado.IdEtapa).Count()>0)
                {
                    var tiempoAntes=_context.EtapaEmpleado.FirstOrDefault(z=>z.IdEmpleado==preEtapaEmpleado.IdEmpleado && z.IdEtapa==preEtapaEmpleado.IdEtapa);
                    var condicion=String.IsNullOrEmpty(tiempoAntes.TiempoParc);
                    if(condicion==false)
                    {
                        string[] arrTAntesStr=tiempoAntes.TiempoParc.Split(':');
                        string[] arrTDespuesStr=preEtapaEmpleado.TiempoParc.Split(':');
                        int[] tiempoAntesArrInt= Array.ConvertAll(arrTAntesStr,Int32.Parse);
                        int[] tiempoDespuesArrInt=Array.ConvertAll(arrTDespuesStr,Int32.Parse);
                        int[] tiempoIntFinal={0,0,0,0};
                        int meLlevoUno=0;
                        string tiempoStringFinal=null;
                        
                        for(int i=3;i>-1;i--)
                        {
                            switch(i){
                                default:
                                    
                                 tiempoIntFinal[i]=tiempoAntesArrInt[i]+tiempoDespuesArrInt[i]+meLlevoUno;
                                    meLlevoUno=tiempoIntFinal[i]/60;
                                    tiempoIntFinal[i]=tiempoIntFinal[i]%60;
                                    break;
                                case 0:
                                        tiempoIntFinal[i]=tiempoAntesArrInt[i]+tiempoDespuesArrInt[i]+meLlevoUno;
                                        break;
                                case 1:
                                    tiempoIntFinal[i]=tiempoAntesArrInt[i]+tiempoDespuesArrInt[i]+meLlevoUno;
                                    meLlevoUno=tiempoIntFinal[i]/24;
                                    tiempoIntFinal[i]=tiempoIntFinal[i]%24;
                                    break;
                    
                            }
                        }

                        
                        var builder = new StringBuilder();
                        for(int j=0;j<tiempoIntFinal.Length;j++)
                        {
                            if(tiempoIntFinal[j]<10)
                            {
                                builder.Append("0");
                            }
                            builder.Append(tiempoIntFinal[j]);
                            if(j!=3)
                            {
                                builder.Append(":");    
                            }
                            
                            tiempoStringFinal=builder.ToString();
                        }   

                        preEtapaEmpleado.TiempoParc=tiempoStringFinal;

                    }
                    

                    try{
                        
                        //preEtapaEmpleado.TiempoParc=preEtapa.TiempoParc;
                        _repo2.Update(preEtapaEmpleado);
                           

                    }
                    catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException){
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    try{

                        _repo2.Add(preEtapaEmpleado);
                    }
                    catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                await _repo2.SaveAsync(preEtapaEmpleado);
            }

             _repo.Update(preEtapa);
            await _repo.SaveAsync(preEtapa);
            return StatusCode(201,preEtapa);
```

And this is my IDataRepository:

```
namespace Foha.Repositories
{
    public interface IDataRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        void Add(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        Task<T> SaveAsync(T entity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

`var tiempoAntes=_context.EtapaEmpleado.FirstOrDefault(z=>z.IdEmpleado==preEtapaEmpleado.IdEmpleado && z.IdEtapa==preEtapaEmpleado.IdEtapa);`

It starts tracking that entity in `_context`. I assume that `_repo2` use the same `_context`?

If that is true, then when you try to add a copy of the object `_repo2.Update(preEtapaEmpleado);` with the same id, the context recognizes it as a duplicate and throws the error.

This article might help

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Comment: Great! . 
Effectively, `_repo ` and `_repo2 `uses the same `_context`... 
That article works for me and helped me to resolve this issue adding `AsNoTracking()` method to `tiempoAntes`. 
Thank you very much!